# python - the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have the below code in which I am trying to hash an image and set the output in a text file, later I am encrypting the txt file and I need to delete the old version of it. However, I am receiving the following error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I have tried to use time.sleep(3) to delay the code but I am still receiving the same error.
or should I be using .close() and how to set it?

can someone please advise?

```
import os
import hashlib
import logging
import time
import cryptography
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
file = open('key.key', 'wb')  # Open the file as wb to write bytes
file.write(key)  # The key is type bytes still
file.close()
file = open('key.key', 'rb')  # Open the file as wb to read bytes
key = file.read()  # The key will be type bytes
file.close()


logging.basicConfig(filename='InitializationHash.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(message)s')

def hash_image(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        file_bytes = f.read()
        hash_text = hashlib.sha256(file_bytes).hexdigest()
        logging.info(hash_text)

def get_one_image(file_Name):
    filepath = os.path.abspath(file_Name)
    hash_image(filepath)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   get_one_image("initializationlandmark.png")
   
input_file = 'InitializationHash.txt'
output_file = 'InitializationHash.encrypted'

with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()  # Read the bytes of the input file

fernet = Fernet(key)
encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted)  # Write the encrypted bytes to the output file
    

os.remove("InitializationHash.txt")
```

Comment: InitializationHash.txt seems to be used as logfile and something else (`input_file`) at the same time. But the error message should tell which line causes the problem, perhaps consider showing it too. Delaying an error by 3 seconds usually doesn't fix it, that's normal.

Comment: yes but the main issue is how to close the dependency. in other words, how to allow the os. remove("InitializationHash.txt") command to run perfectly in the same code.

Comment: @tevemadar the line causing the problem indicates that the issue is in the os. remove("InitializationHash.txt"). I need to delete the file after taking the data from it.

Comment: Try to call https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown before that line.

Comment: Perfect @tevemadar worked fine for me. 
Thank you Dear.